# MongoDB with Python, used to store username and passwords for a game

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo-3.x

This is the part where the user logs in into the game. The database is hosted on mlab, there is a collection of documents named `loginInfo` defined as `mycol`.

The problem that I am facing is that when it returns the id, I have no way of checking if it is a valid one since I would not be able to check with any sort of local list in Python. How do I fix it?

```
import pymongo

def login():
    print('Login\nRegister\nPlay as Guest')
    login_input = input('What would you like to do?')
    if login_input == 'Login':
        username = input('Username:')
        username_fromDB = mycol.find({"username": username})
        if username_fromDB == username:
            password = input('Password:')
            password_fromDB = mycol.find({"password": password})
            if password == password_fromDB:
                print('Login success!\n')
                mainMenu()
    elif login_input == 'Register':
        new_username = input('Username:')
        new_password = input('Password:')
        tobeaddedtodb = {"username": new_username, "password": new_password}
        adding = mycol.insert_one(tobeaddedtodb)
        print("Registered!\n")
    elif login_input == 'Play as Guest':
        mainMenu()
```

Comment: "...checking if it is a valid one.." - What do you mean by validation here?

Comment: By validation, I meant that if the username doesn't exist, I would ask the user to register, and it also serves the purpose of finding the password linked to the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
username_fromDB = mycol.find({"username": username})
```

This is wrong because `find()` returns a cursor object, not the username as you expect.

---

Assuming that `loginInfo` collection contains unique usernames and respective passwords, there's no need to make 2 `find()` queries to database. You can just retrieve a user entity and check if input-provided password matches the one stored in database.

And since usernames are unique, you should use `find_one()` instead of `find()`. If user was successfully found it returns `dict`, otherwise you get `None`.

Try something like this:

```
import pymongo

def login():
    print('Login\nRegister\nPlay as Guest')
    login_input = input('What would you like to do?')

    if login_input == 'Login':
        username_inp = input('Username:')
        pwd_inp = input('Password:')

        user_found = mycol.find_one({"username": username_inp})  # query by specified username
        if user_found:  # user exists
            if pwd_inp == user_found['password']:
                print('Login success!\n')
                mainMenu()
            else:
                print('Wrong password')
        else:
            print('User not found')
    elif login_input == 'Register':
        new_username = input('Username:')
        new_password = input('Password:')
        tobeaddedtodb = {"username": new_username, "password": new_password}
        adding = mycol.insert_one(tobeaddedtodb)
        print("Registered!\n")
    elif login_input == 'Play as Guest':
        mainMenu()
```